# How to recognize dynamic keys while using JsonSerializable in Flutter?

Tags: flutter, dart

Let's assume, until recently, I was getting the bellow `Json response`

```
{
   "AA": {
         "product": {
            "id":"111",
            "type":"C"
         }
    }
}
```

And, I have written the bellow, `model.dart` to convert from json to object

**model.dart**

```
@JsonSerializable()
class ResponseGate {
  @JsonKey(name: "AA")
  AA aa;

  ResponseGate({this.aa});
  factory ResponseGate.fromJson(Map<String, dynamic> json) =>
      _$ResponseGateFromJson(json);
}

@JsonSerializable()
class AA {
  @JsonKey(name: "product")
  Product product;

  AA(this.product);
  factory AA.fromJson(Map<String, dynamic> json) => _$AAFromJson(json);
}

@JsonSerializable()
class Product {
  @JsonKey(name: "id")
  var id;
  @JsonKey(name: "type")
  var type;

  Product(this.id, this.type);
  factory Product.fromJson(Map<String, dynamic> json) =>
      _$ProductFromJson(json);
}
```

And, then the response becomes as bellow. Just another object is added.

```
{
   "AA": {
       "product": {
           "id":"111",
           "type":"C"
       }
   },
   "BB": {
       "product": {
           "id":"222",
           "type":"d"
       }
   }
}
```

Just the keys (AA & BB) are different but their children are keys are the same. What do I have to do to enable my code to recognize all the keys and use the `model.dart` to convert from json to model?

```
if (thirdResponse.statusCode == 200) {
  var map = json.decode(thirdResponse.body) as Map<String, dynamic>;
  ResponseGate responseGate = new ResponseGate.fromJson(map);
else {
  throw Exception('Failed to load post: ${thirdResponse.statusCode}');
}
```

Comment: Did you mean the JSON from api use `object` instead of `array` in the array case? If this is true, you might need to write custom parser first, and then using `JsonSerializable` after parsed.

Comment: Can you show me how to do  custom parser?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I saw you have the decoded map, so here is the code, I tested in [dartpad](https://dartpad.dartlang.org/).

1. Iterate `Map`,

```dart
  var data ={
   "AA": {
       "product": {
           "id":"111",
           "type":"C"
       }
   },
   "BB": {
       "product": {
           "id":"222",
           "type":"d"
       }
   }
  };

  var list = new List();
  data.forEach((key, value){
    list.add(value);
  });

  print(list);
```

2. Transform To `Product`

```dart
for(var productInfo in list)
{
  Product product = new Product.fromJson(productInfo);
  // add product to your List...
}
```

Or you could combine both, and get the key also.

```
  data.forEach((key, value){
     Product product = new Product.fromJson(value);
     // add product to your List...
     // or make a Map to store (key, product)
  });
```

But there is an alternative way, modify api to array, and make more sense on json response.

```
[
   {
       "productName": "AA"
       "id":"222",
       "type":"d"
   }
]
```

Just kidding for final approach because you didn't talk too much about your scenario.

Answer (score -4):

don't use models try to put your response in a map
then for example

```
{
   "AA": {
       "product": {
           "id":"111",
           "type":"C"
       }
   },
   "BB": {
       "product": {
           "id":"222",
           "type":"d"
       }
   }
}
```

if you want "BB" "product" "id"
it will be somthing like that

```
map['BB']['product']['id']
```

Comment: can someone explain why ?