# Convert object to array in flutter

Tags: flutter

I need to convert object to array in flutter , Kindly find the json

```
{
  "billing": [
    {
      "id": 1,
      "add_id": 23
    }
  ],
  "shipping": [
    {
      "id": 2,
      "add_id": 345
    },
    {
      "id": 3,
      "add_id": 345
    }
  ]
}
```

I need to convert into array and map to model in flutter , how to do it

Comment: This may help you: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57968307/how-to-convert-json-objects-to-json-array-in-flutter?rq=1

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to recognize dynamic keys while using JsonSerializable in Flutter?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57593624/how-to-recognize-dynamic-keys-while-using-jsonserializable-in-flutter)

Comment: Does this answer your question? [<String, dynamic>' is not a subtype of type 'List<dynamic>' flutter](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65796626/string-dynamic-is-not-a-subtype-of-type-listdynamic-flutter)

Answer (score 0):

Use the following code to convert your JSON to a class object, the fromJson function convert JSON to object, and the toJson function convert the object to json.

```
class YourClassName {
  List<Billing> billing;
  List<Shipping> shipping;

  YourClassName({this.billing, this.shipping});

  YourClassName.fromJson(Map<String, dynamic> json) {
    if (json['billing'] != null) {
      billing = new List<Billing>();
      json['billing'].forEach((v) {
        billing.add(new Billing.fromJson(v));
      });
    }
    if (json['shipping'] != null) {
      shipping = new List<Shipping>();
      json['shipping'].forEach((v) {
        shipping.add(new Shipping.fromJson(v));
      });
    }
  }

  Map<String, dynamic> toJson() {
    final Map<String, dynamic> data = new Map<String, dynamic>();
    if (this.billing != null) {
      data['billing'] = this.billing.map((v) => v.toJson()).toList();
    }
    if (this.shipping != null) {
      data['shipping'] = this.shipping.map((v) => v.toJson()).toList();
    }
    return data;
  }
}

class Billing {
  int id;
  int addId;

  Billing({this.id, this.addId});

  Billing.fromJson(Map<String, dynamic> json) {
    id = json['id'];
    addId = json['add_id'];
  }

  Map<String, dynamic> toJson() {
    final Map<String, dynamic> data = new Map<String, dynamic>();
    data['id'] = this.id;
    data['add_id'] = this.addId;
    return data;
  }
}

class Shipping {
  int id;
  int addId;

  Shipping({this.id, this.addId});

  Shipping.fromJson(Map<String, dynamic> json) {
    id = json['id'];
    addId = json['add_id'];
  }

  Map<String, dynamic> toJson() {
    final Map<String, dynamic> data = new Map<String, dynamic>();
    data['id'] = this.id;
    data['add_id'] = this.addId;
    return data;
  }
}
```